# Remove div's with almost the same id once a certain top value is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-edge

So I've got this code to create a rectangular div every 800ms which falls down the screen.
Now I'd like to be able to remove a div once it reaches a certain top value, otherwise it'll
get too cluttered with div's. Now I have no idea how to exactly do that, considering the id's I've given them. I'd also like to know how I could end up removing every single one of those div's once it's game over. This is what I have so far all together: http://student.howest.be/pieter-jan.vandenb1/crossdodger/Game.html. I'm pretty new at javascript so thanks in advance!

```
var idNumber = 0;

        SpawnBlock();

        function SpawnBlock()
        {
            UpdateBlock();
            setTimeout(SpawnBlock, 800);
        }



        function UpdateBlock()
        {

            var block = document.createElement("div");
            block.style.width = "25px";
            block.style.height = "25px";
            block.style.background = "lightgrey"
            block.style.top = "-25px";
            block.style.left = Math.random() * 455 + "px";
            block.style.position = "absolute";
            block.id = "block" + ++idNumber;
            //block.speed = 0.5;
            sym.$("Stage").append(block);
            sym.$("#block"+idNumber).transition({top:"800px"},8000,"linear");

        }
```

It's made in Adobe Edge, hence the "sym." namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a similar environment:

```
 var bl = document.getElementById("block" + (idNumber));
 bl.parentNode.removeChild(bl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var idNumber = 0;

        SpawnBlock();
        
        var divblocks = [];

        function SpawnBlock()
        {
            UpdateBlock();
            setTimeout(SpawnBlock, 800);
        }



        function UpdateBlock()
        {

            var block = document.createElement("div");
            block.style.width = "25px";
            block.style.height = "25px";
            block.style.background = "lightgrey"
            block.style.top = "-25px";
            block.style.left = Math.random() * 455 + "px";
            block.style.position = "absolute";
            block.id = "block" + ++idNumber;
            //block.speed = 0.5;
            sym.$("Stage").append(block);
            sym.$("#block"+idNumber).transition({top:"800px"},8000,"linear");
            divblocks.push(block.id);
            if (divblocks.length > 800)
            {
              $(divblocks[0]).Remove();
            }
        }
```